# Limit point of sequence and the limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I'm reading Robinson's *Non-standard Analysis* and I'm having some struggles about the following two definitions related to the convergence of a sequence:

> **Limit of a sequence.**
>
> For a Hausdorff topological space $(X,\tau)$, the limit of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ is $p$ if for any given neighborhood $U$ of $p$ there exists a natural $m$ such that $x_n\in U$ for $n>m$.

> **Limit point of a sequence**
>
> For a topological space $(X,\tau)$, $p$ is a limit point of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is $p$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and every natural $m$, $x_n\in U$ for some $n>m$.

I already see a lot of questions but I can't found a clear answer about topological spaces. Obviously, one of the definitions implies the other, but is not clear (for me, at least) how these definitions are different. This is also important, because Robinson treats directed sets and nets, and the proofs about those objects are related to their counterparts in sequences.

Comment: A limit is a limit point (obviously) . $0$ is a limit point of $\{0,1,0,1,0,1....\}$ but it is not the limit of the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

$p$ is the limit of a sequence if every neighborhood $U$ of $p$ contains *all but finitely* many points of the sequence.  You want the space to be Hausdorff because that makes the limit unique (if it exists).  Consider disjoint neighborhoods $U_p$ and $U_q$ of $p$ and $q$, respectively.  Since the neighborhoods are disjoint, they can't both contain all but finitely many points of an infinite sequence.

$p$ is a limit point of a sequence if every neighborhood $U$ of $p$ contains *infinitely many* points of the sequence.  This is a weaker condition than in the previous paragraph because some neighborhoods may have infinitely many points of the sequence both inside and outside the neighborhood.  Thus, a sequence can have more than one limit point.

Think of a sequence that alternates between $\frac 1n$ and $1 - \frac 1n$.  Any neighborhood of $0$ or of $1$ contains infinitely many points of the sequence, but many neighborhoods of either fail to contain all but finitely many points of the sequence.